# Gather elements from tensor with an inner batch dimension in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'll present my actual problem, and then a simpler version that is more easily reproducible.

### My actual problem

I have a tensor that represents a batch of images from my training data. Its shape is:

```py
[domains, batch_size, image_size, image_size, channels] = [4 x 4 x 64 x 64 x 4]
```

The 64x64x4 images are pixel art character sprites, and the `domains` dimension represent images of them in: back, left, front, and right poses. The reason that the `batch_size` dim is not the outer-most is that the images are read from a `tf.data.Dataset` that produces a 4-tuple for each sample (character in the back, left, front, and right poses). And when I do `next(iter(dataset))`, what I get is a tensor with the mentioned shape (`[domains, batch_size, image_size, image_size, channels]`).

At each training step, I need to randomly pick a target pose for each image in the batch, so I can ask a generator to translate them from their source into a target pose. I am using `tf.gather` for this, but it does not correctly select images the way I need. My code:

```py
batch_size = 4
domains = 4
batch = next(iter(dataset))  # shape 4 x 4 x 64 x 64 x 4
# back, left, front, right = batch

target_indices = tf.random.uniform(shape=[batch_size], dtype="int32", maxval=domains)
target_images = tf.gather(batch, target_indices, axis=0)

print("Shape of target_images", tf.shape(target_images))
# 4 x 4 x 64 x 64 x 4
```

I need the resulting `target_images` to have a shape of `[4, 64, 64, 4]`, which would be 1 image for each character sprite in the randomly picked target pose. But as per the documentation of `tf.gather`, *"the output shape has the same shape as the input, with the indexed-axis replaced by the shape of the indices."*

One option is to use the `batch_dims=1` argument of `tf.gather`, doing:

```
batch_size = 4
domains = 4
batch = next(iter(dataset))  # shape 4 x 4 x 64 x 64 x 4
# back, left, front, right = batch

target_indices = tf.random.uniform(shape=[batch_size], dtype="int32", maxval=domains)
target_images = tf.gather(batch, target_indices, axis=1, batch_dims=1)

print("Shape of target_images", tf.shape(target_images))
# 4 x 64 x 64 x 4
```

...that does yield a tensor with the correct shape, but not with the correctly gathered subtensors: in the simplified example I show next it is easier to see what is going on. The reason is that although the `batch_dims` argument exists, it seems to require the batch dimension(s) to be the outer-most one(s). Let' move on to a simpler problem.

### Simplification (reproducible)

Suppose we have a tensor with a shape of:

```py
[domains, batch_size, content] = [2, 3, 1]
```

I want to be able to gather one element (`content`, `axis=2`) for each element in the batch (`axis=1`) according to some random domain (`axis=0`). Let's try some code:

```py
batch_size = 3
domains = 2
batch = tf.constant([
  [ [1],  [2],  [3]],
  [[10], [20], [30]]
])
target_indices = tf.constant([0, 1, 1])  # randomly picked indices to gather

# the batch has 3 elements and I want to get the content of domain 0 for the first element,
# and domain 1 for the second and third: [[1], [20], [30]], with shape (3, 1)
#
# attempts:
tf.gather(batch, target_indices, axis=0)
# shape=(3, 3, 1) ❌
# [[[ 1], [ 2], [ 3]],
#  [[10], [20], [30]],
#  [[10], [20], [30]]] 

tf.gather(batch, target_indices, axis=1)
# shape=(2, 3, 1) ❌
# [[[ 1], [ 2], [ 2]],
#  [[10], [20], [20]]] 

tf.gather(batch, target_indices, axis=1, batch_dims=1)
# InvalidArgumentError: params.shape[0]: 2 should be equal to indices.shape[0]: 3 [Op:GatherV2] ❌


# last attempt: permute the batch tensor so the batch dim becomes the outer-most
permuted_batch = tf.transpose(batch, [1, 0, 2])
print("Shape of permuted_batch", tf.shape(permuted_batch)) # (3, 2, 1)
tf.gather(permuted_batch, target_indices, axis=1, batch_dims=1)
# shape=(3, 1)
# [[1], [20], [30]] ✅
```

As we can see, permuting the tensor to put the batch dimension as the outer-most allows me to use `batch_dims=1, axis=1` for `tf.gather` and yields the correct result. However, I'm a bit afraid of the performance of `tf.transpose`.

**My question**: is there some way I can gather the desired elements of a tensor that has a batch dimension as an inner dimension?